# Using block for callback from different class

Tags: objective-c, callback, block

I have spent quite a bit of time reading about blocks, but for some reason it's very difficult for me to fully understand them. It's worth mentioning I'm a newbie developer, but blocks are the first real 'block' I've come across, so maybe you can help me.

I have a case where an object (instance of a ViewController) is talking to a class (via a class method - it's a utility class I've set up to request/get data). I want to implement a method with a callback using a block. Here are my current 'understandings' that I based my code on:

- A block can be passed as a method argument;
- A block can be called like a function.

OK, so here's my (simplified) method in my utility class:

```
+ (void)getDataWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {

    //Some code...
    completion(YES);
}
```

And this is how I call the method from my viewController:

```
[ClassName getDataWithCompletion:^(BOOL gotData) {

    if (gotData) {
        NSLog(@"Called");
    }
}];
```

Naturally, I was expecting that NSLog to be printed on my console, but alas... I know I am doing something wrong here, could someone please point that out? Any rookie-level explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`... that is reserved for special cases where the method returns multiple items by reference.  Note also that if your method executes asynchronously, you'll need to copy the block to keep it around until completion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of not using 'get' to start method names, I'll have to go through my code and change it in a few places. Is 'fetch' a safe word to use?

Comment: `fetch`, `download`, `retrieve`, or simply `dataWithCompletion:`.   Or `loadDataAsynchronouslyWithCompletion:` if you go there.  Or `loadDataSynchronouslyWithCompletion:`.   Anything but *get*. :)

Comment: Just tried your example. All works fine in ios7 simulator! And your code seems to be fine also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mistake is really simple. You forgot a parameter name.
Cahnge your method to this.
**(BOOL gotData)** this is what you have missed.

```
+ (void)getDataWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL gotData))completion {

    //Some code...
    completion(YES);
```

}

Here is link to apple documentation [apple block documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html)

Comment: How about that, you were right. Thanks @Konstantin. The code now works. Hm... I thought that it's optional to declare input variables in this place, nor did I get a compiler error...

Comment: This is wrong. Parameter names are not part of a block type, and in fact should generally not be included.

Comment: if you made what I suggested, xcode will make make autocompletion of function declaration with correct parameter name

and here in apple documentation it says 
"Argument name" if you want to use argument you need to give a name to it.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Art/blocks.jpg